# Verify a Microsoft Partner id

Tags: windows

I would like to verify a Microsoft Partner Id however after checking pages like http://partners.microsoft.com, I haven't been able to find a simple Microsoft website where you just put that integer id and returns the partner profile.

Does Microsoft have a page to verify someone's claim to be it's partner on Windows 10 licenses?

Comment: Websites are off topic here and a companies partner status with another company isn't a problem with computer *hardware or software*.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed and voted down.  I need to verify a few Microsoft Partners to make sure they are legit...

Comment: Shawn: because stackoverflow has a quite a toxic community. You can't see the comments because they were deleted already but believe me, they interrogate why are you making that question/if it's useful/offtopic, rather than trying to answer it. Except for the guy that actually did it. (they only care about the points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a MPN id is required to sell Windows keys as you're asking. Microsoft doesn't provide a website to check MPN (Microsoft Partner Network) ids, but you can verify them by:

- Phone calling https://support.microsoft.com/es-co/help/4051701/global-customer-service-phone-numbers (When asked, choose Enterprise)
- If you have the required credentials (must be another partner), using their API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-partner-by-mpn-id